# Algebra Problem Finding More Reps To Work

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

I am not a math major so please take it easy on me. I am trying to figure this out for a real situation and could use all help necessary.

Problem: There are $4$ reps. who process $32$ transactions in $3$ minutes ($180$ seconds). I want to finds out **how many more reps.** do I need to **minimize** that time down to **$0.30$ seconds**.

My Working: which does not answer the above question

I know $3$ minutes $=$ $180$ seconds.

We want to find out $w$ $=$ $.30$ seconds.

We have $32$ transactions which processes within $180$ seconds.

We can find out how long $1$ transaction takes: $\frac{32}{1}$ $=$ $\frac{180}{x}$

Solving gives us: $x$ $=$ $5.625$ seconds.

We can also find out how many transactions $1$ rep. can process: $\frac{4}{1}$ $=$ $\frac{32}{y}$

Solving gives us: $y$ $=$ $8$ transactions.

Since we know $1$ rep. processes $8$ transactions and it takes $5.625$ seconds to process $1$ transaction we can say:

($8$ transactions)($5.625$ seconds) $=$ $45$ seconds

Which means: it takes $1$ rep. $45$ seconds to process $8$ transactions$.

However, this **does not** give me the solution to the problem I am looking for. I basically found out for $1$ rep. instead of finding out **how many more reps needed** to break down the time to **$.30$ seconds**.

HELP PLEASE! Please can someone give me a formula for this too once it's shown how to actually solve this problem. I have been working on this all day!

Edit: I got it now. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Half a minute is 30 seconds, not 0.30 seconds.

Comment: @Boshu I meant $0.30$ seconds. As you can see, I've been working on this for a while.

Comment: I'll edit my answer to reflect this but the comment should give you the answer already.

Answer (score 1):

You want the job done 6 times faster, so you need six times the reps.  So 24 reps altogether (or 20 "more" than you have now.

Comment: I know I'm going to sound not so intelligent but I want to make certain that I understand. How did you get $6$ times faster? Did you divide $180$ by $.30$? That would give us $600$ unless we move over the two decimal places. Did you also multiply $6$ and $4$ to give you $24$? I'm sorry! My head is hurting from this. Can you show your work? Is there also a formula you might have?

Comment: Sorry, but I meant .30 seconds.

Comment: Then it's 600 times as much.  But now each rep does only a fraction of a transaction, and that's probably physically impossible.  However long it takes one rep to do one transaction is as fast as you can get all the transactions done.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, throw out the number of transactions. It stays the same, so it shouldn't matter.

Second; $4$ people do something in $3$ minutes. To do it in half the time, i.e. $1.5$ minutes, how many people do you need? Twice. In other words $4\times3/1.5=8$ people. So you need to find out by what factor your time is decreasing, and you must *increase* the number of people by the same factor.

So your answer will be $4\times3/0.5=24$ people. Or, since you already have $4$ people, $20$ more people.

This is also called the [rule of three](https://www.smartickmethod.com/blog/math/rule-of-3/) by some people.

Edit: For 0.30 seconds, you do the same thing but now you compare $4\times180/0.30=2400$. You need to compare equivalent units, so convert 3 minutes to 180 seconds.

Comment: I followed the steps right until the very last part. Can you show how you got $0.5$ if you don't mind. Sorry! I feel like I'm getting closer to understanding.

Comment: Half a minute, or $0.5$ minutes. You can convert all of it to seconds, in which case $3$ minutes is $180$ seconds and half a minute is $30$ seconds.

Comment: I meant 0.30 seconds. It was a typo. Can you show me a solution to the 0.30 seconds if possible. Sorry.

Comment: I did but it is really the same process with changed values and you should *really* try to understand how and why it works instead of looking for an answer. Read the link attached in my answer.

Comment: @Emily Do you really mean $3/10$ of a second, not $30$ seconds? If so, then you are really trying to do the same amount of work in $1/600$ of the time. You want to do $32$ transactions that used to take $5.6$ seconds each in about $0.01$ seconds each?

Comment: @EthanBolker I meant 3/10 or $.30$ seconds. If that's the case, then is the above solution correct. I solved and got $2400$ or $2396$ more reps. since we already have $4$.

Comment: @Emily OK.You do realize that now each rep does $4$ transactions but in the new scheme of the thousands of reps will do only  a fraction of a transaction ... it will take rep cooperation to get the processing time down to $0.01$ seconds per transaction.

Comment: @EthanBolker Yes. Thanks.

Comment: @Boshu I got it now. Thanks.